# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync Opens popup only once Office 365 Word online

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins

Developing a Word Addin using OfficeJS,

From the Ribbon button click calling a function called "faq()" in FunctionFile.js like below:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/UI/FAQ.html",
            { height: 50, width: 60, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);
```

Word 2016, MAC everywhere that works fine, but O365 word online, popup opens only once, when the second click is made from ribbon button, it reacts nothing.

I couldn't further track it, why this is happening !

Comment: Does it happen if you set displayInFrame to false?

Comment: please add full code for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Usually, after a dialog box pops up, the previous dialog box needs to be closed to display the second dialog box. However, 
using dialog.close() cannot close the first dialog box, because the first dialog is still in memory and has not been cleaned up. 
Use dialogCloseAsync() to address this problem.

The following link is the used of Dialog for your reference

The following link is reference for **Use of Dialog Box**

[enter link description here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md)

This is the link I think might help you to solve your problem.

[enter link description here](https://theofficecontext.com/2017/07/27/officejs-second-dialog-does-not-display/)